# Removing Google Map V3 additional styles and links from head

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, cmsmadesimple

I am working in CMS Made Simple 1.11.11 and normally, this is what my `<head>` looks like on most pages...

```
<head>
<base href="http://np.dev/">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="language" content="en_US">
<meta name="url" content="http://np.dev">
<meta name="identifier-URL" content="http://np.dev">
<meta name="revised" content="Sun, 19 Oct 2014 23:00:50">    
<title>My localhost demo site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://np.dev/tmp/cache/stylesheet_combined_b494846cba46cad77e309f4df2e3bfe7.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://np.dev/tmp/cache/stylesheet_combined_d3f3ceb94300bf27c9a51ce2e1404348.css">
...
</head>
```

The above layout is fine.  But if I attach and run Google Maps v3 API onto this template, Google Maps will prepend several `<style>` and `<link>` elements to the `<head>`
producing the following....

```
   <head>
   /*I WANT TO USE JQUERY TO REMOVE THESE 5 ELEMENTS WHEN THE WINDOW IS READY*/
   <style type="text/css">.gm-style .gm-style-mtc label,.gm-style .gm-style-mtc div{font-weight:400 </style>
   <style type="text/css">.gm-style .gm-style-cc span,.gm-style .gm-style-cc a,.gm-style .gm-style-mtc div{font-size:10px}</style>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
   <style type="text/css">@media print {  .gm-style .gmnoprint, .gmnoprint {    display:none  }}@media screen {  .gm-style .gmnoscreen, .gmnoscreen {    display:none  }}</style>
   <style type="text/css">.gm-style{font-family:Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none}</style>

    <base href="http://np.dev/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="language" content="en_US">
    <meta name="url" content="http://np.dev">
    <meta name="identifier-URL" content="http://np.dev">
    <meta name="revised" content="Sun, 19 Oct 2014 23:00:50">    
    <title>My localhost demo site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://np.dev/tmp/cache/stylesheet_combined_b494846cba46cad77e309f4df2e3bfe7.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://np.dev/tmp/cache/stylesheet_combined_d3f3ceb94300bf27c9a51ce2e1404348.css">
    ...
    </head>
```

I don't think its possible to "prevent" the first 5 `<head>` child elements from loading onto the DOM from Google Maps API, so I want to do the next best thing...I want to use jQuery to remove these elements from the `<head>` once the window is ready.  Is this possible?

Comment: What about overriding those CSS properties in your stylesheet leting them `inherit` the default values?

Comment: I would do that as a last resort - But initially I want to go for a "cleaner" look once the DOM is ready and not have stuff sitting on top of my base element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting all the head `style` and `link` elements this way would work as you can expect, adding an `lt()` selector would limit the selection to the first N of each type.

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

```
$(function() {
    $('head style[type="text/css"]:lt(4)').remove();
    $('head link[type="text/css"]:lt(1)').remove();
});
```

Overriding the properties set by Google may be a more maintainable solution.

Comment: You may add an :lt() selector in order to remove exactly the first 4 <style>s and the first <link> elements; I have updated the above code. Problems may occur if Google Maps changes the number of tags added, or if any other script prepend Google ones with any additional <style>/<script>.

Comment: I have a slight adjustment I had to make.  I instead did style lt(2), then link lt(1), then style lt(2).  Thank you!

Comment: I also see that this works...   $('base').prevAll().remove();

Answer (score -1):

Problem : My site was acting weird with all the fonts being bold and i found out that < head > has above unwanted style sheet.

Solution:I was using the following line of code in the css file  and i removed the following line of code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
```